# How can I call my image up from desktop or folder in Python?

Tags: python, image

```
import pygame
import sys
from time import sleep


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
padWidth = 480     # Width of game screen         
padHeight = 640     # Height of game screen



def initGame():
    global gamePad, clock, background
    pygame.init()
    gamePad = pygame.display.set_mode((padWidth, padHeight))
    pygame.display.set_caption('SPACE INVADERS')   # Title of game
    background = pygame.image.load('background.png')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def runGame():
    global gamepad, clock, background

    onGame = False
    while not onGame:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type in [pygame.QUIT]:     # Quit game program
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        gamePad.fill(BLACK)     #game screen is black

        pygame.display.update() #draw game screen

        clock.tick(60)      # Frame per second of game screen

    pygame.quit()   # QUit game

initGame()
runGame()
```

***This is my code for game screen, for inserting background, I used pygame.image.load('file name'). But the background image doesn't pop up, and it says FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory. The image file is on both my desktop and folder, and I didn't type the different file name. What should I do?***

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the path of the file instead of just the file name?

Comment: background = pygame.image.load('This PC/Desktop/PyShooting/background.png')                        but still not working

Comment: Maybe try to put it in another directory